# ServiceStack version compatibility

Tags: servicestack

I saw a lot of bug fixes in ServiceStack.Text which I want to upgrade, but i can't upgrade ServiceStack at this point.

Is ServiceStack.Text.dll version 3.9.4.0 compatible with ServiceStack.dll 3.6.9.*

I couldn't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We try hard to avoid making any backward incompatible changes, but no testing has been done with older vs new dll configurations.

The [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) releases maintain the same version numbers on all the different components and are designed to co-incide with each other and should be deployed in lock-step together at the same time.